# Android: manifest targetSdkVersion change resulted in: icon not visible, widget no longer works, and cannot access data

Tags: android, android-widget, android-manifest

I recently upgraded my Android app to support multiple resolutions.  Previously, my Android.manifest file had a line:

To support multiple density and resolution devices, I changed this to:

```
<supports-screens
 android:smallScreens="false"
 android:normalScreens="true"
 android:largeScreens="true"
 android:anyDensity="true"
/>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="4" />
```

I then added a couple of new directories, like drawable-hdpi-v4 and drawable-long-hdpi-v4 that includes the high-res versions of the graphics.  That's about it.

Ever since releasing this update, there have been a decent number of users complaining about various problems:

- the app icon doesn't appear  (I did not create a high res version of the icon)
- the home screen widget no longer works, even if they delete and re-add it (this code did not change with the update).  I've had a user send me their error log, which shows:

  `03-19 20:59:41.617 W/ActivityManager( 1854): Unable to launch app com.alt12.babybump/10078 for broadcast Intent { action=android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE flags=0x4 comp={com.alt12.babybump/com.alt12.babybump.WidgetGirl} (has extras) }: process is bad`

There is one questionable section in my existing widget code that may be relevant:

```
@Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

  // v1.5 fix that doesn't call onDelete Action
  final String action = intent.getAction();
  if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED.equals(action)) {
   final int appWidgetId = intent.getExtras().getInt(
     AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
     AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
   if (appWidgetId != AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
    this.onDeleted(context, new int[] { appWidgetId });
   }
  } else {
   super.onReceive(context, intent);
  }
 }
```

And perhaps most troublesome: `the sqlite database is no longer accessible/writeable for some users so their data is no longer available`.  I did add the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to the manifest.  This is only happening to certain users and it tends to be HTC Eris users.  In that error log I see things such as:

```
03-19 16:00:56.173 E/FlurryAgent( 4791): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.alt12.babybump/files/.flurryagent.-2333f5cb
03-19 16:00:56.173 E/FlurryAgent( 4791): at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(OSFileSystem.java:231)

03-19 16:01:09.393 E/Database( 4791): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.alt12.babybump/databases/uitematmamad.db", &handle, 6, NULL) failed
03-19 16:01:09.393 W/System.err( 4791): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file
```

It's as if the update has caused a new process and it can't access the old process's data, or something.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

this combination goofed it up:

I then added a couple of new directories, like drawable-hdpi-v4 and drawable-long-hdpi-v4 that includes the high-res versions of the graphics.

remove the drawable-**-v4 directories and put graphics in the drawable-** folders..that will fix your graphics

On the other errors..have you checked the Motorola android devloper forums yet?